# iPhone Mapview update Callout View

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, cllocation, callouts

Wonder how I can change the callout view of the pins, depending on my different current userLocation. The Pin stay still at some place.
For example, a pin is settled at the church. 
If I am at home, I want the callout of the pin show message @"the distance from home to church is what what what"
If I am at school, I want the callout of the pin show message @"the distance from school to church is what what what"

how can I update the callout view? which method should I use in the delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is delegate method of `MKMapView` which call when you tap pins calloutbutton

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

and for annotationView (for view of pins ) use bellow delegate method..

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```